# strcmp causing seg fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I seem to be getting a seg fault when using `strcmp`: weirdly the value seems to be the right value stored but still causes a seg fault. Does anyone have any ideas why this is my code?

Say for example I have 'xx' as the value I want to unalias in the 2 lines after the for loop they both = 'xx' but then this line causes a seg fault `if (alias_array[i].alias != NULL && strcmp(alias_array[i].alias, arguments[1]) == 0) {`

```
typedef struct alias {
    char alias[50];
    char command[50];
} alias;

alias alias_array[MAX_ALIAS_LEN];

void unalias_command(char *arguments[50]) {
    char alias_name[50];
    strcpy(alias_name, arguments[1]);
    printf("args[1] %s\n", *arguments);
    printf("Len of args = %ld", strlen(arguments[1]));
    //if(strcmp(alias_name, NULL) != 0) {      
    if (arguments != NULL) {
        int found = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < MAX_ALIAS_LEN; i++) {
            printf("current name = %s\n", alias_array[1].alias);
            printf("current argument = %s\n", arguments[1]);
            if (alias_array[i].alias != NULL && strcmp(alias_array[i].alias, arguments[1]) == 0) {
                // if alias is found and matches then we can use the free() function
                found = 1;
                strcpy(alias_array[i].alias, NULL);
                strcpy(alias_array[i].command, NULL);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found == 1) {
            printf("Alias, %s has been removed as an alias\n", arguments);
        } else {
            printf("No alias with name %s\n", arguments[1] );
        }
    } else {
        printf("Error: command 'unalias' requires 1 argument"); }
}

... 

char *args[50] = {""}
unalias_command(args)
```

Comment: Your "2 lines after the for loop" (or the first of those) shows the value of `alias_array[1].alias` but the `strcmp` uses `alias_array[i].alias` (`i` is not the same as `1`). As you haven't shown us what/where/how `alias_array` is declared or initialized, we can only guess that the array contains invalid string data.

Comment: What is `alias_array`? If it is an array of `alias` then `alias_array[i].alias != NULL` makes no sense. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the fault.

Comment: @WeatherVane i have now editted it with alias_array within the code under the typedef declaration

Comment: @AdrianMole i have now editted it with alias_array within the code under the typedef declaration

Comment: @jDownUnder OK, but the answer I have posted is still valid, as is that given by chqrlie.

Comment: @AdrianMole i tried that is still seems to cause a seg fault and chqrlie's answer isnt hte reason because as i said under his answer i printf arguments its not null i get output correctly it just doesn't seem to like when i do the strcmp in the if statement i even tried `if( alias_array[i].alias[0] != '\0' && strcmp(alias_array[i].alias, arguments[1]) == 0) {` and i still get a seg fault

Comment: Then there must be some error in code or initialization data that you haven't shown us. `strcmp` will segfault if either of its arguments are not valid (`nul`-terminated) `char` arrays. Further, as your previous `printf` *appears* to show that `arguments[1]` is what you expect, we can assume that its the `alias_array[i].alias` value that's causing the problem.

Comment: @AdrianMole what is even weirder is it does not seem to seg fault if i do `if( alias_array[i].alias[0] != '\0' && strcmp(alias_array[i].alias, arguments) == 0) {`

Answer (score 2):

If you pass an array of strings that contains a single empty string and 50 null pointers:

```
    char *args[50] = {""}
    unalias_command(args)
```

You get a segmentation fault here:

```
   strcpy(alias_name, arguments[1]);
```

and here:

```
   printf("Len of args = %ld", strlen(arguments[1]));
```

Further problems:

- the members of the `alias` structure are not pointers, so it makes no sense to compare `alias_array[i].alias != NULL`
- `strcpy(alias_array[i].alias, NULL);` has undefined behavior. You should instead write `strcpy(alias_array[i].alias, "");` or simply `*alias_array[i] = '\0';`

You should pass the count of arguments and the argument array, as `main()` receives, and you must check for proper usage before proceeding with the command handing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct alias {
    char alias[50];
    char command[50];
} alias;

alias alias_array[MAX_ALIAS_LEN];

int unalias_command(int argc, char *arguments[50]) {
    char *alias_name;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unalias: missing argument\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // no need to copy the alias, just use a char pointer
    alias_name = arguments[1];
    if (alias_name[0] != '\0') {
        int found = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ALIAS_LEN; i++) {
            if (strcmp(alias_array[i].alias, alias_name) == 0) {
                // if alias is found and matches then we can reset it
                found = 1;
                *alias_array[i].alias = '\0';
                *alias_array[i].command = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            printf("Alias `%s' has been removed as an alias\n", alias_name);
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("No alias with name `%s'\n", alias_name);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @chqlie my bad args is not empty btw because i am making a shell it is just 600+ lines so i cannot include all lines that isnt the problem that was just my initilasation of args

Comment: @jDownUnder: OK, but there are other problems as explained in my expanded answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the check `if (alias_array[i].alias != NULL)` is actually not doing anything meaningful. The `.alias` member is declared as a *fixed* `char[50]` array so, in that expression, it will decay to a pointer (to the first element of that array). That cannot be `NULL` (in any meaningful dataset).

You need some other method for testing if the `alias_array[i].alias` member represents a valid string. Possibly, `if (alias_array[i].alias[0] != '\0')`.